# How to remap a key on OS X El Capitain without external software?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keypad

I have 2 candidates :

- the `<` touch is inverted with `²`
- I'd like the keypad to use `.` not `,`

I cannot install software, just using what's already there.

Exception if it's installable with `homebrew`

Any clue ?

EDIT: I use an azerty pc105 keyboard with mapping 'french PC'

Comment: Both look like your input language doesn't match your actual keyboard. You need to check & add the info to your question.

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Comment: This isn't really my area of expertise, but I've heard that Canadian French  might be what you're looking for - it would certainly be worth testing your options if you type 'french' in System Prefs > Keyboard > Input sources & hit the + at the bottom

Comment: Thanks, but it's worth :)

Comment: Fixed by using another keyboard :/

Comment: Hmm... ok - glad you got there in the end :)